# Cant set input value via JS after manually deleted the value (Chrome & FF)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Im creating a simple HTML form that lets you click on a text and set the value in an input field.

The problem is when I manually delete the value, I cant click and set a new value.

I created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4faujvo/

```
    document.getElementById("pnr").setAttribute("value", this.textContent);
```

*(Click on 2222 and 9999 to see it change, delete/blank the value manually, click on 222 or 999 again)*

- IE9: **Working**
- FF 25: **Not working**
- Google chrome 30.0.1599.66: **Not working**

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Value is a property, not an attribute**. To access, use:
`document.getElementById("pnr").value=this.textContent;` .

Comment: Now thats embarrassing :-D Thanks!